# Why can't I move this face without it extruding?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I don't know how else to explain it. I just want to move the face back, pulling the existing faces next to it back a little bit with it. Instead, it creates new faces like I'm extruding, even though I'm not. How can I make it only move, not make the new faces?

Here's a gif of what's happening:
[image]

Comment: I believe there is a small loop around the face you select. As you select the face and move it the small loops faces are stretched and it looks like you extrude.